# Kaplan-Meier Subsetting/Selecting Strata for Comparison

Tags: kaplan-meier

When comparing different strata how legitimate is it to merge or eliminate single strata, especially if they represent an intermediate level in order to provide a comparison. Each strata relate to three locations along a bone - distal, middle, proximal and its proclivity for reinjury after repair. For example when comparing three strata I got

[image]

Eliminating the middle strata.

[image: Example1]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's hard to answer this question as posed, as there's no information on what the strata represent. If they are binned groupings of a continuous variable you probably [shouldn't even analyze your data this way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500), reserving Kaplan-Meier plots for display of illustrative situations. Please edit your question to include more information about the nature of your strata. Comments are easy to overlook and can get deleted.

Comment: @EdM Each strata relate to three locations along a bone - distal, middle, proximal and its proclivity for reinjury after repair. Put it in above!

Answer (score 1):

Changing your analysis in the way that you propose would be considered inappropriate in terms of any claim of "statistical significance" for the final nominal p-value. You altered your analysis based on results that you found in an initial analysis, so the assumptions that go into defining a p-value don't hold for the second analysis. You certainly can explore your data that way to help design future studies, but you shouldn't report a "statistically significant" result based on your second Kaplan-Meier plot.

In your case, the initial analysis might have been inadequate. It did not take the *ordering* of your `location` predictor in terms of "proclivity for reinjury" into account. The log-rank test used to evaluate differences among strata didn't incorporate the information that you expect an *ordering* in survival curves among the strata.

You might consider coding `location` as an [ordinal categorical predictor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/195246/28500) and performing Cox regression instead. In R, ordered categorical predictors are coded differently from unordered predictors, in a way that takes the order into account. That linked thread is a good place to start. If you do further web searches for "ordinal" be careful, as much of what you find might have to do with ordinal outcome variables rather than ordinal predictor variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that you are implicitly sidestepping the necessary multiple hypothesis correction. Imagine a scenario where you have 100 groups instead of just 3, and all of the groups have the same hazard rate. By chance alone, some of those groups will have better-than-expected survival and some will have worse. If you look at the curves and then choose to compare the best survivors and the worst survivors, you're implicitly ignoring all the other tests that you ran "by eye" - you've visually identified which curves aren't very different and specifically chosen to ignore them, but your p-value calculation pretends those other curves *don't even exist*. It's poor statistical practice to run lots of tests and only report the most significant ones, which is effectively what's happening when you filter out the other curves by the "eye test".