# Encoding ordinal categories as features

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, ordinal-data, feature-engineering

When we have categorical features in a regression (say a generalized linear model for now), it is typical to let one category be subsumed by the intercept and then code binary indicator variables for each of the remaining categories, so “cat” could be subsumed by the intercept, “dog” would be coded as $(1,0)$, and “horse” would be coded as $(0,1)$.

If these were ordered categories (e.g., small/medium/large), a such an encoding would lose the order. A remedy I have seen is to build up to the highest level, so the lowest level is subsumed by the intercept, then the second-lowest level has one $1$, the next-lowest level has two $1$s, and so on: medium would be $(1,0)$, and then large would be $(1,1)$.

This seems to take care of the issue. We get an indicator for each level, but we build up to the higher levels to enforce an order. The “large” size had its indicator turned on, yes, but it also turns on an indicator for the lower size(s).

Is this the standard way to approach ordinal encoding? I do believe I have read about it (perhaps on Cross Validated). What would be the drawbacks to this kind of encoding m, and what remedies to those drawbacks exist?

Comment: I do not think the idea makes any statistical sense. Most often, ordinal relation is tackled by means of polynomial contrasts. This is one of ghe threads on ordinal regressors https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/195246/3277